# Array[key].push Is Not Defined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

When trying to push items to an array in javascripts it gives an error, the following pseudo code illustrate what is happening:

```
var data = new Array();
for(...) {
     data[key].push(item[i]);
}
```

It is showing the following error:

```
   Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Thanks

Comment: Because `data` is the array. Unless `data[key]` holds an array, you're going to get undefined. Consider `var data = [1,2,3,4,5];` and `key` is the first index (1). You're trying to use an array method on an integer, which obviously wont work.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Has given you the answer.

Comment: You can learn the basics about arrays from tutorials and documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array, http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html . *Maybe* you want `data[key] = item[i]`.

Comment: Did you expect `data[key]` to already be an array?

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes I want to make data[key] also an array like array of an array, I was wonderring if I need to define it as 2d array like:
data = [[]], or such a thing

Comment: @MohanadKaleia yes, you have to do that.

Comment: @FelixKling I know the basics about array thanks!, but I was wondering if I want to explicit define the data type of data to be an array of array, like in PHPno need to define the data type of variables the interpreter will detect it automatically

Comment: If you want any of the values to be an array you have to create it first. You should update your question to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @wateriswet defining 2d array like this is not working: data = [[]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a 2d array, you have to initialize each element of the outer array to be an array.

```
// Have to check every array item, if it's not an array already, make it so
for(...) {
    if (!data[key]) {
        data[key] = [];
    }
    data[key].push(item[i]);
}
```

You could always do the following if you know the number of inner arrays you need:

```
var data = [[],[],[],[],[],[]];
```

In your example, since they variable name is key, I'm assuming you actually want an object of arrays. If you know the keys ahead of time, you can use the following literal.

```
var data = {
  myKey1: [],
  myKey2: []
}
```

Comment: You define an array of data[key] supposed that you know the key, but in my case the key is defined during the runtime, inside a for loop

Comment: But I don't know the key ahead, I don't know how many of them I need, thats my problem, I need to look for a dynamic way to define 2d array,
Thanks,

Comment: Then first snippet of code is what you're looking for

Comment: I will try it .. thanks

Comment: Ok that worked, but I had to had all keys ahead, but I made it,
thanks